# Can't get PHP DOMXpath substring functions to work

Tags: php, xpath

Using the following PHP code sample:

```
$xml = "<person><name>John-Doe</name></person>";
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-15");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("substring-before(/person/name/text(), '-Doe')");
print "Found " . $nodelist->length . " results.";
```

I get the output:

> Found 0 results

But when I put the same XML and xpath query into online Xpath testers, I get the expected result, which is "John"

I also can't seem to get any results using substring() and substring-after().  Is something up with PHP's DOMXpath, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: PHP's DOMXPath says it [*"Supports XPath 1.0"*](http://php.net/manual/class.domxpath.php) but `substring-before` was added in 1.0.4.2 so it *may* not be supported. In any case, this is the kind of thing PHP would be able to do easily once you've retrieved the `person/name` text; why bother trying to do it in XPath?

Answer (score 3):

XPath [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) function returns `string` instead of node, and you're not supposed to use `DOMXPath::query()` to execute XPath expression that doesn't return node(s)*. [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) is the correct function to be used here :

```
$xml = "<person><name>John-Doe</name></person>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->evaluate("substring-before(/person/name/text(), '-Doe')");
print $result;
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/480222)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
John
```

*) Quoted from [**DOMXPath::query** > **Return Values**](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) :

> **Any expression which does not return nodes will return an empty `DOMNodeList`.**